# UICollectionView doesn't show

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, xcode8

I've got a UICollectionView in one of my ViewControllers but it doesn't show at all. I have no idea why it's like that. I've already written the code for the two different types of cells that I've got and all the other code for the CollectionView but it doesn't work.

If you guys need any kind of information, I'll be glad to give it to you but I'm not going to do it right away because there are so many places where the problem could have occurred so I'm not going to post all of it at once. I hope you understand.

Fyi: My code is written in swift 3 just so you know and I've already tried cleaning my project and disconnection the CollectionView from the code and reconnection it again.

Thank you very much

I really need your help because I have no idea why it is like that.

ALright so here's the code:

```
class AddPersonViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, APCodeCollectionCellDelegate {
```

then there's some stuff in between and also the outlets

Here I've set the datasource and the delegate

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
```

Here I've done some customizations

```
collectionView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 2/255, green: 11/255, blue: 57/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    collectionView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 15 
    collectionView.clipsToBounds = true
```

And lastly here's all the code for the datasource

```
//Collection View Cells

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return person.codes.count + 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.row < self.person.codes.count {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CodeCell", for: indexPath) as! APCodeCollectionViewCell

        cell.codeTextView.text = person.codes[indexPath.row].code
        cell.nameLabel.text = person.codes[indexPath.row].title
        cell.isFavorite = person.codes[indexPath.row].favorite

        cell.codeTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 15

        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 4

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        cell.delegate = self

        return cell

    } else {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AddCell", for: indexPath) as! APAddCodeCollectionViewCell

        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 4

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        return cell
    }
}
```

I really hope this helped, else I'm just gonna do it all over again...

Comment: have you set delegate and datasource of collectionview??

Comment: check datasource and delegate provided or not and secondly look array being used for collection view must not be nil

Comment: Need to see the code mate :D

Comment: I've added the code now

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected your delegate and data source from collection view and to viewcontroller enter image[image]

Answer (score 0):

First Check your delegate And dataSource is connected or not, if not then set the delegate and dataSource :-

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource { 
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self 
 }
```

In swift 3 some time problem is coming for not importing the UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource.
If you don't import these files then please check the delegate methods or use these name in delegate methods cellForItemAtIndexPath, numberOfItemsInSection

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
}
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

press ctrl and drag you uiimageView to inside your controller 
make the same thing with your label and inside yourController 
do your staff.

Comment: how cntrl+drag of image view will show collection view?

Comment: the same way you use the table view or another collector type implement the delegate's and so on you should create a custom-class and use the references in this custom uicollectionview